# Параметры конфигурации Qt из исходников

Tags: qt, qt5

Настраиваю Qt для статической сборки:

```
./configure \
        -platform linux-g++ \
        -release \
        -static \
        -fontconfig \
        -opensource \
        -confirm-license \
        -nomake examples \
        -nomake tests \
        -qt-zlib \
        -qt-libpng \
        -qt-libjpeg \
        -no-ssl \
        -prefix ${LIB_DIR}
```

получаю следующее:

```
Build options:
 Mode ................................... release
 Optimize release build for size ........ no
 Building shared libraries .............. no
 Using C++ standard ..................... C++1z
 Using ccache ........................... no
 Using gold linker ...................... yes
 Using new DTAGS ........................ yes
 Using precompiled headers .............. yes
 Using LTCG ............................. no
 Target compiler supports:
   SSE .................................. SSE2 SSE3 SSSE3 SSE4.1 SSE4.2
   AVX .................................. AVX AVX2 F16C
   AVX512 ............................... F ER CD PF DQ BW VL IFMA       VBMI
 Build parts ............................ libs tools
  Qt modules and options:
    Qt Concurrent .......................... yes
    Qt D-Bus ............................... yes
    Qt D-Bus directly linked to libdbus .... yes
    Qt Gui ................................. yes
    Qt Network ............................. yes
    Qt Sql ................................. yes
    Qt Testlib ............................. yes
    Qt Widgets ............................. yes
    Qt Xml ................................. yes
 Support enabled for:
   Using pkg-config ....................... yes
   QML debugging .......................... yes
   udev ................................... yes
   Using system zlib ...................... no
 Qt Core:
   DoubleConversion ....................... yes
     Using system DoubleConversion ........ no
   GLib ................................... yes
   iconv .................................. no
   ICU .................................... yes
   Logging backends:
     journald ............................. no
     syslog ............................... no
     slog2 ................................ no
   Using system PCRE2 ..................... yes
 Qt Network:
   getaddrinfo() .......................... yes
   getifaddrs() ........................... yes
   IPv6 ifname ............................ yes
   libproxy ............................... no
   OpenSSL ................................ no
     Qt directly linked to OpenSSL ........ no
   SCTP ................................... no
   Use system proxies ..................... yes
 Qt Gui:
   Accessibility .......................... yes
   FreeType ............................... yes
     Using system FreeType ................ yes
   HarfBuzz ............................... yes
     Using system HarfBuzz ................ yes
   Fontconfig ............................. yes
   Image formats:
     GIF .................................. yes
     ICO .................................. yes
     JPEG ................................. yes
       Using system libjpeg ............... no
     PNG .................................. yes
       Using system libpng ................ no
   EGL .................................... yes
   OpenVG ................................. no
   OpenGL:
     Desktop OpenGL ....................... yes
     OpenGL ES 2.0 ........................ no
     OpenGL ES 3.0 ........................ no
     OpenGL ES 3.1 ........................ no
   Session Management ..................... yes
      Features used by QPA backends:
   evdev .................................. yes
   libinput ............................... yes
   INTEGRITY HID .......................... no
   mtdev .................................. no
   tslib .................................. no
   xkbcommon-evdev ........................ yes
 QPA backends:
   DirectFB ............................... no
   EGLFS .................................. yes
   EGLFS details:
     EGLFS i.Mx6 .......................... no
     EGLFS i.Mx6 Wayland .................. no
     EGLFS EGLDevice ...................... yes
     EGLFS GBM ............................ no
     EGLFS Mali ........................... no
     EGLFS Raspberry Pi ................... no
     EGL on X11 ........................... yes
   LinuxFB ................................ yes
   VNC .................................... yes
   Mir client ............................. no
   X11:
     Using system-provided XCB libraries .. no
     EGL on X11 ........................... yes
     Xinput2 .............................. yes
     XCB XKB .............................. yes
     XLib ................................. yes
     XCB render ........................... yes
     XCB GLX .............................. yes
     XCB Xlib ............................. yes
     Using system-provided xkbcommon ...... no
 Qt Widgets:
   GTK+ ................................... no
   Styles ................................. Fusion Windows
 Qt PrintSupport:
   CUPS ................................... yes
 Qt Sql:
   DB2 (IBM) .............................. no
   InterBase .............................. no
   MySql .................................. no
   OCI (Oracle) ........................... no
   ODBC ................................... no
   PostgreSQL ............................. no
   SQLite2 ................................ no
   SQLite ................................. yes
     Using system provided SQLite ......... no
   TDS (Sybase) ........................... no
 Qt SerialBus:
   Socket CAN ............................. yes
   Socket CAN FD .......................... yes
 QtXmlPatterns:
   XML schema support ..................... yes
 Qt QML:
   QML interpreter ........................ yes
   QML network support .................... yes
 Qt Quick:
   Direct3D 12 ............................ no
   AnimatedImage item ..................... yes
   Canvas item ............................ yes
   Support for Qt Quick Designer .......... yes
   Flipable item .......................... yes
   GridView item .......................... yes
   ListView item .......................... yes
   Path support ........................... yes
   PathView item .......................... yes
   Positioner items ....................... yes
   ShaderEffect item ...................... yes
   Sprite item ............................ yes
 Qt Gamepad:
   SDL2 ................................... no
 Qt 3D:
   Assimp ................................. yes
   System Assimp .......................... no
   Output Qt3D Job traces ................. no
   Output Qt3D GL traces .................. no
 Qt 3D GeometryLoaders:
   Autodesk FBX ........................... no
 Qt Wayland Client ........................ no
 Qt Wayland Compositor .................... no
 Qt Bluetooth:
   BlueZ .................................. no
   BlueZ Low Energy ....................... no
   Linux Crypto API ....................... no
 Qt Sensors:
   sensorfw ............................... no
 Qt Quick Controls 2:
   Styles ................................. Default Material Universal
 Qt Quick Templates 2:
   Hover support .......................... yes
   Multi-touch support .................... yes
 Qt Positioning:
   Gypsy GPS Daemon ....................... no
   WinRT Geolocation API .................. no
 Qt Location:
   Geoservice plugins:
     OpenStreetMap ........................ yes
     HERE ................................. yes
     Esri ................................. yes
     Mapbox ............................... yes
     MapboxGL ............................. yes
     Itemsoverlay ......................... yes
 Qt Multimedia:
   ALSA ................................... no
   GStreamer 1.0 .......................... yes
   GStreamer 0.10 ......................... no
   Video for Linux ........................ yes
   OpenAL ................................. no
   PulseAudio ............................. yes
   Resource Policy (libresourceqt5) ....... no
   Windows Audio Services ................. no
   DirectShow ............................. no
   Windows Media Foundation ............... no
 Qt WebEngine:
   Embedded build ......................... no
   Pepper Plugins ......................... yes
   Printing and PDF ....................... yes
   Proprietary Codecs ..................... no
   Spellchecker ........................... yes
   WebRTC ................................. yes
   Using system ninja ..................... no
   ALSA ................................... no
   PulseAudio ............................. yes
   System libraries:
     re2 .................................. no
     ICU .................................. no
     libwebp and libwebpdemux ............. no
     Opus ................................. no
     ffmpeg ............................... no
```

Где можно почитать про параметры сборки?

Хочется понять как настроить все параметры перечисленные выше

Answer (score 2):

Все, как всегда, оказалось просто....

./configure --help